# Send binary string via WebSocket in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, tcp, websocket, binary

I have been trying to send binary data via WebSocket in vain.

The data:

```php
$buff=chr(1);
$buff.=chr(2);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(6);
$buff.=chr(1);
$buff.=chr(6);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(192);
$buff.=chr(0);
$buff.=chr(1);
```

It works using PHP, but I can't achieve what I want to using PHP, I can only rely on JavaScript.

**PHP**
This works fine:

```php
$length = strlen($this->buff);
$sent = socket_write($socket, $this->buff, $length);
```

**JS**
This one does not:

```js
var data="<?= $buff ?>";
WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION="WebSocketMain.swf";
var ws= new WebSocket("ws://10.0.0.60:502");

ws.onopen=function(){

    ws.send(data);
}
```

Desired data to be sent:

```
01 02 00 00 00 06 01 06 00 C0 00 01
```

Data sent by a WebSocket:

```
47 45 54 20 2F 20 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 0D 0A 48 6F 73 74 
3A 20 31 30 2E 30 2E 30 2E 36 30 3A 35 30 32 0D 0A 43 6F 6E 
6E 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 3A 20 55 70 67 72 61 64 65 0D 0A 50 72 
61 67 6D 61 3A 20 6E 6F 2D 63 61 63 68 65 0D 0A 43 61 63 68 
65 2D 43 6F 6E 74 72 6F 6C 3A 20 6E 6F 2D 63 61 63 68 65 0D 
0A 55 70 67 72 61 64 65 3A 20 77 65 62 73 6F 63 6B 65 74 0D 
0A 4F 72 69 67 69 6E 3A 20 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 6C 6F 63 61 
6C 68 6F 73 74 0D 0A 53 65 63 2D 57 65 62 53 6F 63 6B 65 74 
2D 56 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 3A 20 31 33 0D 0A 55 73 65 72 2D 41 
67 65 6E 74 3A 20 4D 6F 7A 69 6C 6C 61 2F 35 2E 30 20 28 57 ...
```

How can I send the right data using a WebSocket?

Comment: use `ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';`  and send data as Array buffer